# Radio Control car telemetry

Tags: rf, wifi

I am trying to get some input on the feasibility of this project. I will have a radio controlled car. The car will have sensors that will output data like acceleration, gyro something like 6DOF. A similar sensor will be on the helmet of the driver of the car to control a camera on the RC car. So if the driver turns the camera will turn at the same time. Video streaming also needs to come from the car for the virtual driver.

**Signals from car**

- X
- Y
- Z
- Acceleration
- video

**Signals to car**

- Head Position X Y Z
- Throttle
- Braking
- Steering

Traditionally RC cars are controlled by burst of AM but I think the best method for transmitting all this data is via wifi? Would it be fast enough to be realistic with little latency? Or just stick with regular methods?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do something similar to FPV quadcopters which I believe use a 5.8GHz system.

Comment: Hey that is a great tip. thx

Answer (score 1):

The devices like [RN171](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11049) can transmit a video feed (given you have a controller powerful enough to feed video data to wifi module). It is possible with such modules.

But I would not advice to go with wifi
as:-

1) It will limit the range of your video feed depending on the wifi range

2) It becomes highly complex to send live feed from digital camera to a wifi module. Processor needs to be fast enough not only to receive the camera feed bu also to transmit it to wifi module.

Thus I would advice you go for wireless cameras as it takes a lot of complex work off you. It also increases your range way more than a normal wifi hotspot/ router.